# How to perform operations on each row of a matrix without for loop?

Tags: octave

I want to vectorize the following operations on 2 matrices.

A is a "k x m" matrix and B is a "n x m" matrix. I have defined a function F(a, B) which operates on a row "a" of A and the whole matrix B. The output of F is a "1 x n" row vector.

I want to apply F(a, B) to each row of A and stack up the k "1 x n" resultant row vectors to form the final "k x n" matrix. This operation, when using for loop, is :

```
result = [];
for i = 1:k
  result = [result ; F(A(i,:),B)];
endfor
```

Does anyone have idea on how could I eliminate the for loop in this operation ? Could I use something like the "bsxfun" Octave built-in function ?

As a new comer in Octave, I am sorry if I have missed some obvious ways in performing such operations.

Thanks for any suggestion.

EDIT :
In fact, B could be encapsulated. I could define a function f(a) instead which operates on a "1 x m" row "a" of A such that the output of f is a "1 x n" row vector. Then my operations, when using for loop, would become :

```
result = zeros(k,n);
for i = 1:k
  result(i,:) = f(A(i,:));
endfor
```

I need to operate an entire row, A(i,:), once at a time as the function f needs the whole information in A(i,:) to produce an output row vector.

As m,n could be large (several ten thousands or more), I am looking for ways to eliminate the simple for loop to try to make the program runs even faster.

I am wondering whether Octave has some built-in functions for vectorizing my such case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some study, I could finally vectorize my code by using "mat2cell", "cellfun" and "cell2mat".
The idea is to turn each row of A into a cell entry of a cell C, and then apply f(a) to each cell entry of C, and finally convert the resultant cell back into a matrix. The code is :

```
C = mat2cell(A, ones(1,size(A,1)));
f = @(a) F(a,B);
result_cell = cellfun(f, C, "UniformOutput", false);
result = cell2mat(result_cell);
```

However, the running time of this vectorized code seems nearly the same as the original "for loop" implementation. It seems that the one level "for loop" is NOT very inefficient, or the difference only arises when k is large (i.e. A has many rows). Moreover, the "cellfun" built-in may be not so efficient as its help states :

> The `cellfun' function is a useful tool for avoiding loops.  It is often used with anonymous function handles; however, calling an anonymous function involves an overhead quite comparable to the overhead of an m-file function. Passing a handle to a built-in function is faster, because the interpreter is not involved in the internal loop.

Hope my answer a good reference for others too.

Comment: Then, to run in parallel on multiple cores, you could replace `cellfun` with `parcellfun`: `result_cell = parcellfun(nproc, f, C, "UniformOutput", false);`. Here is a starting page for `parcellfun`:http://wiki.octave.org/Parallel_package

Comment: There is an even more compact solution with the `ndpar` package I just uploaded; more info in my solution

Comment: @huntj The "parallel" package seems good. For my case, A has several rows and B has several hundred rows, and both have several ten thousands columns, and a few hundreds iterations are being run. Using "parcellfun" reduces the running time to about 60% compared with "cellfun". The "parcellfun" function could utilize nearly 100% of all the 4 cores of my desktop computer. I'll try your suggested "ndpar" package for comparing results.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `ndpar` package, http://wiki.octave.org/NDpar_package,
you can achieve this quite directly

```
pkg load ndpar

k = 3;
m = 2;

A = rand(k, m);
B = rand(m, k);

F = @(a, B)  a * B;

result_ndpar = ndpar_arrayfun(nproc, F, A, B, "IdxDimensions", [1, 0], "CatDimensions", [1])
```

The `"IdxDimensions"` option `[1, 0]` means that the first argument `A` should be sliced (parallelized) along the first direction and the second argument `B` should not be sliced (hence passed "as is")

The `"CatDimensions"` option `[1]` means that the output values should be concatenated along the first direction.

Comment: The "ndpar" package is more flexible/powerful. Using "ndpar_arrayfun" reduces the running time to about 65% compared with "cellfun". It seems slightly slower than "parcellfun". However, this package seems conflict with the "parallel" package and could not be simultaneously installed/loaded with it, otherwise it sometimes hangs during my iterations and I need to use "ctrl-c" to abort Octave. It works normally if only "ndpar" is installed/loaded. Thanks.

Comment: @user1129812  Many thanks for the feedback. Usually speedups are much higher (more than 3 on a quadcore). And the compatibility problem did not show up here yet, but this is a bug, I'll try fix that. Here are the two tickets I created based on your report, it should be a better place than comments. Hope it is OK for you ? performance: https://sourceforge.net/p/ndpar/tickets/2/ and compatibility: https://sourceforge.net/p/ndpar/tickets/1/.

Comment: @user1129812 The low performance is probably due to the function F being too fast, relative to the parallelization overhead.

Comment: Compatibility problem is fixed since the 1.1.0 version, thanks to @user1129812 feedback on sourceforge.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that F(a, B) is something like:

```
function F(a, B)
for i=1:size(B,1)
    result = f(a,B(i,:));
end
```

so I would start from here, and apply f(a, b) on each corresponding rows:

```
A = repmat (A, [n 1]); 
B = repmat (B, [k 1]); %(kxn) x m matrix
```

Comment: After the "repmat", A and B would have the same size. However, the i-th row in A does not correspond to the i-th row in B for my operations. Moreover, m,n could be large, so "repmat" may not be efficient in this case.

Comment: Hi, Would you elaborate on what the function is doing?

Comment: For my this case, F(a,B) is multiplying each element of "a" to each column of B and then perform a sum over the second dimension. However, what I want is a general approach for vectorizing my this case for any function F(a,B). I think I have achieved this goal (see my answer), but it seems that I could not get a large speed gain. The one level for-loop in my question seems NOT very inefficient.

Comment: so, F(a,B)=sum(a*B,2)?

Answer (score 1):

First you should check that the `for` loop is taking a considerable amount of time before expending too much effort to remove it. Your main problem is that you're reallocating memory on each iteration. Matlab's Editor will warn you about this -I'm not sure about Octave. This isn't a big deal for small arrays, but for larger ones it can be expensive to reallocate many times. You simply need to preallocate:

```
result = zeros(k,n);
for i = 1:k
    result(k,:) = F(A(i,:),B);
end
```

Or you can reverse the direction of indexing and not bother with calling `zeros` (be careful with this technique):

```
for i = k:-1:1
    result(k,:) = F(A(i,:),B);
end
```

To answer your question, `bsxfun` cannot be used for this sort of thing. It's meant for element-wise operations. It's possible that you could use it if you re-wrote your `F` function (or you might be able to accomplish everything with matrix math operations). If you simply want to get rid of the loop for the sake of getting rid of it, you might look at [`arrayfun`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/arrayfun.html). However, `arrayfun` is just a `for` loop in disguise and is often slower than writing the loop explicitly.

Comment: "arrayfun" seems could not solve my problem. However, a similar built-in function "cellfun" solves it. Thanks.